# playframework 2.8.8 - class sbt.internal.inc.MappedVirtualFile cannot be cast to class java.io.File

Tags: java, scala, sbt, playback

I get this error when executing `sbt run`.

Here are my potentially relevant version numbers.

- Play Framework - 2.8.8
- Scala - 2.13.6
- sbt - 1.5.5
- java - 11.0.13
- addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "6.2.0-RC3")

I read these below, but unsure if I missed anything.

1. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/10648
2. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/10649
3. https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt?at=5f6b4a01b8a99f4519a0d3ab

Any idea how to fix this?

```
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1$.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:187)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1$.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:185)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMapKeys.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:149)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:395)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:728)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMapKeys.foreach(HashMap.scala:149)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:189)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:184)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:108)
[error]     at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.$anonfun$ebeanEnhance$1(PlayEbean.scala:113)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
[error] (data / Compile / manipulateBytecode) java.lang.ClassCastException: class sbt.internal.inc.MappedVirtualFile cannot be cast to class java.io.File (sbt.internal.inc.MappedVirtualFile is in unnamed module of loader sbt.internal.MetaBuildLoader @130f889; java.io.File is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: yes i found the issue that why we can not update the version of scala because maven repo can't have an dependency 
    maven repo take dependency to scala 2.13 
   _(https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/)_ ans also you can go with SBT version 1.3.4